# How do nuts fit into the ketogenic diet?

Tags: nutrition, diet

I just got done reading the book, Why We Get Fat, by Gary Taupes.  I found it a fascinating read and I am going to give that eating philosophy a personal 4 month trial.  I am planning my meals and thinking about what I will be eating on a daily basis and I find myself wondering where nuts fit in.  The last Appendix of the book outlines what you should and should not eat and there is no mention of nuts anywhere in that chapter (try it: do a word search in Kindle).  Do nuts carry too many carbohydrates to be considered a good snack while conforming to a ketogenic eating philosophy?

Comment: Are you looking for information on a low-carbohydrate diet, or on an actual [ketogenic diet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketogenic_diet)?

Comment: I am new to the whole low/no-carbs things so I am not sure.  I want to follow the diet recommended in the book I mentioned, which I _think_ is ketogenic.  However, not completely sure.  I am just wondering if nuts are okay.  What about quinoa?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about diet and nutrition are off topic unless they're directly related to medical treatment.